# Stored procedure returns nullable int

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

In my procedure i am returning a int value.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetValue] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @ID int,

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    DECLARE @isNew int
    SET @isNew=0
    DECLARE @returnedValue int
    DECLARE @output int
    SET @returnedValue=[dbo].fn_GetIsNewLecturer(@ID)


    IF(@returnedValue=0)        
        BEGIN
             PRINT 'new'
             EXEC @output=[dbo].[GetNew] @ID
             SELECT @output 
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'old'
            EXEC @output=[dbo].[sp_GetOld] @ID
            SELECT @output  
        END
        RETURN @output
END
```

it return value should be int. But it returns Nullable int?. how to change it as int
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select [Output] = isnull(@output, 0)
```

Here's why it should work:

```
declare @i int

select ni = @i, nni = isnull(@i,0)
into #t

select is_nullable, * 
from tempdb.sys.columns 
where [object_id] = object_id(N'tempdb..#t')

drop table #t
```